# Grails Exception: Mapping qname not fond for the package: grails.validation

Tags: web-services, grails, soap, apache-axis

I am trying to build a simple SOAP web service (basic CRUD) using Grails with Apache Axis2 Plugin.

All works well with methods that have a simple return type (like String, int).

The problem is when I try to retrieve a domain class object:

```
class Hotel {

    static mapping = {

        datasource 'hotel'
        table 'hotel'
        version false

        hotelId column:'id', insertable: false, updateable: false
        hotelName column:'hotel_name', sqlType:'varchar', name:'hotelName'
    }

    Integer hotelId
    String hotelName

    static constraints = {

        hotelId(max: 2147483647)
        hotelName(size:1..100)
    }

}
```

I have the following methods, inside my service class:

```
class HotelService {

    static expose=['axis2']
    boolean transactional = false

    String sayHello(String name) {
       return "Hello ${name}!"
    }

    Hotel soapGetHotel(int id){ 
        return Hotel.get(id)
    }
}
```

Executing a curl for soapGetHotel(int id) gives me this error:

```
| Error 2012-11-13 15:29:46,142 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR engine.AxisEngine  - java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: grails.validation
Message: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: grails.validation
```

Please, see bellow my soap-xml file:

```
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
  soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://ws.com">
    <m:soapGetHotel>    
      <m:id>13</m:id>
    </m:soapGetHotel>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And the curl command:

```
curl --verbose --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/soap+xml" --data @gethotel.xml http://localhost:8080/wsexample/services/hotel
```

I believe it has to do with axis that cannot find the mapping for the object. I tried resolving the issue as it is described in the accepted answer here: [Axis2 not returning own objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069659/axis2-not-returning-own-objects), but no luck, I still get the error.

I followed all steps described in the  [axis2 grails documentation](http://www.grails.org/Apache+Axis2+Plugin) .

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can access the wsdl? Your domain class and service are in the default package or other? It seems a [reported bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPAXIS2-5)

Comment: Yes, I can access the WSDL. The domain class and service are in the default packages.

Comment: And if you change for some specific package, it works?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I tried that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069659/axis2-not-returning-own-objects provided a solution to mapping between XML and objects.

Comment: Please read the full question - I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The Axis plugin is a rather old one and it seems that it has not been updated for the last 3 years. I would suggest to use the CXF plugin al an alternative. In our projects this worked out great!