# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.hibernate.collection

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-axis

I have one set(java collection) in my POJO and this POJO is mapped in hbm file. when i call my web service, it will through following error 
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Mapping qname not fond for the package: org.hibernate.collection

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069659/axis2-not-returning-own-objects

Answer (score 1):

1) Actually, the return type of the Method of Web service should be non-generic.

it should not be Object , or just a List...

so , return a specific Person class object ..if one object of Person class need to return or if list of object is there.....use... list as List

do change....and enjoy....!!!!!

2) This exception can also be there Because of the Mapping that is been Done...
 Your Database table contain record that have not been mapped (just simply inserted..)
delete them